# PHP - read version number in composer.json

Tags: php, version-control, fread

How do I make a script there can tell me what version i run when it stored in composer.json?

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "someLiberyNameHere": "8.3.3.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I think that this is as simple as this since composer.json is a Json file:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('/path/to/composer.json');
$content = json_decode($content,true);

var_dump($content['require']['someLiberyNameHere']);
```

You can also iterate through your dependencies:

```
foreach ($content['require'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```php
\Composer\InstalledVersions::getRootPackage();

\Composer\InstalledVersions::getVersion('vendor/package');
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-runtime.md#installed-versions

Answer (score 0):

You can make composer object [from factory](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Factory.php#L565)
And find your package in repository and give package info.

Comment: What a cryptic reply. A sort of DIY eh?

Comment: That wasn't a permalink, so it goes to the wrong line now.